# Can't save data in the xml file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

Goal:
To be enable to add new data in the xml file based on XML dom in the html document.

Problem:
This code is taken from w3school and then I tried saving the data in the xml, it doesn't save anything after executing the source code.

The code is taken from "http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_nodes_add.asp" - "Insert a Node - insertBefore()".

// Fullmetalboy

---

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="loadxmldoc.js"> 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("books.xml");

newNode=xmlDoc.createElement("book");

x=xmlDoc.documentElement;
y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");

document.write("Book elements before: " + y.length);
document.write("<br />");
x.insertBefore(newNode,y[3]);

y=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book");
document.write("Book elements after: " + y.length);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<bookstore>
<book category="cooking">
<title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
<author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>30.00</price>
</book>
<book category="children">
<title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
<author>J K. Rowling</author>
<year>2005</year>
<price>29.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web">
<title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
<author>James McGovern</author>
<author>Per Bothner</author>
<author>Kurt Cagle</author>
<author>James Linn</author>
<author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>49.99</price>
</book>
<book category="web" cover="paperback">
<title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
<author>Erik T. Ray</author>
<year>2003</year>
<price>39.95</price>
</book>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Have u been able to resolve this issue? I am also stuck at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
x.insertBefore(newNode,y[3]);
```

Try this:

```
xmlDoc.documentElement.insertBefore(newNode, y[3]);
```